# Button blinking on Datatrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, storyboard, datatrigger

I would like to have a button that blinks/animate when triggered by DataTrigger. I want to animate the button's background. Below is my xaml code.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.Notification}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.Notification}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="158,62,320,224" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="Button" Focusable="False" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,146,0,0" Name="btnImgBrush" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"></Button>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here are the back end code:

```
public Boolean Notification
    {
        get { return new_notification; }

        set 
        {
            new_notification = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Notification");
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Notification)
        {
            Notification = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Notification = true;
        }
    }
```

But, it didn't work. Any ideas why it didn't work?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You cannot animate Background Property Like this..animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.

Comment: Where have you declared your Notification Property..?? In viewmodel or behind code..??

Comment: Yes, i have declared Notification Property in viewmodel. Is there any other way to animate the button background based on Notification property?

Comment: try my code..I hope it helps You..Its working fine :)

Comment: It not working on my side. :(

Comment: I have upated my answer check it now..!!

Comment: Hi Farzi. At last I'm able to see some progress. Can i know what is the function of "RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"?? But now im facing another problem where an exception is thrown. 'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(Background).(0)'. I believe this is regarding the button background color change. How to solve this?

Comment: Since your property is defined in behind code of your view you need to give relativesource.RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" will give a path to your property because your view doesnt know about tht property but your window is due to datacontext. So you need to make that property available to the Button by giving a relativeSource

Comment: can you update your code again

Comment: Hi Farzi, i have found the solution.. Thank you very much for the help.. :) Please see my working code below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At last its working. Thanks :)

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.Notification}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.Notification}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
 <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Notification,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Transparent" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Notification,,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="False">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: can you show your viewmodel code where you have defined notification property..? and some more xaml code

Comment: I have edited the question and added the other xaml code and viewmodel code where I have defined notification property.

Answer (score 0):

Both *TM Rocket* and *Vishal* answer are correct but probably the following is the most correct and clean way to do it

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.Notification}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```