# Animation causes button to become invisible

Tags: wpf, animation, button, eventtrigger

I've been trying to get a user control to animate when `IsEnabled` changes.

Loosely based on this post [Button Blinking on DataTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009572/button-blinking-on-datatrigger)

However, when I include the `ControlTemplate` style the button is invisible. :)

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.UserControls.MainButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="32" />-->
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
        Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
        ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding ButtonImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the triggers to the `Style` and avoid overriding the `ControlTemplate` if you want the `Button` to still look like a `Button`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This worked in allowing the buttons to be visible. However, I'm not sure you can trigger an animation in IsEnabled...at least my code doesn't do anything 

Answer (score 1):

The template defines the visual appearance of the control. Anything not put there by the template isn't there. Your template puts no visual elements in the control. Therefore, there is nothing visual to be seen.

If you're replacing the template, at absolute minimum, you'll have to give it a `ContentPresenter` inside a `Border` that will show the blinking `Background` brush color:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter
            />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="StartBlinking">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="00:00:00.4" RepeatBehavior="3" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartBlinking"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But if you're happy with the standard `Button` template, use mm8's approach instead, which leaves that in place. Rewriting standard templates usually turns out to be a lot more effort than it's worth, if you can find another way to do what you need to.

Comment: Yes, I see this now. Definitely wanting to rewrite the template. +1 for that.